# How the right term of the derivative is gained?

Tags: derivatives, systems-of-equations

This deduction is one of the typical ones I think.

What I want to deduce is the right term from the left term of the below equation.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\log\left(\frac{a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}}{x}\right)\right)=\frac{-a}{x\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}}$$

$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\log\left(\frac{a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}}{x}\right)\right)$

$=\left(\frac{x}{a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}}\right)\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}}{x}\right)$

$=\left(\frac{x}{a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}}\right)\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^{-1}\left(a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}\right)\right)$

$=\left(\frac{x}{a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}}\right)\left((x^{-1})'\left(a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}\right)\right)\left(x^{-1}\frac{d}{dx}\left(a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}\right)\right)$

$=\left(\frac{x}{a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}}\right)\left((-1\cdot x^{-2})\left(a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}\right)\right)\left(x^{-1}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}\right)\right)$

$=\left(\frac{x}{a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}}\right)\left(-x^{-2}\left(a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}\right)\right)\left(x^{-1}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\left(a^{2}+x^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\right)$

Anyone deduced it in someday?

ps. I have to go to work. Back after about 7hours.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. It would be nice if you edit your post and tell what you have tried, what do you know about rules of differentiation, functions, etc. A no-context question (just the problem without any further details) might attract downvotes and closevotes.

Comment: I'll add my try.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: Sorry for the mention, but just to tell, here is another positive!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\log\left(\frac{a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}}{x}\right)\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\log\left(a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}\right)\right)-\frac 1x$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\log\left(a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}\right)\right)=\frac{\Big[a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}\Big]' }{ a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}}$$
$$\Big[a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}\Big]'=\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2} \left(\sqrt{a^2+x^2}+a\right)}-\frac{1}{x}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{x\left(\sqrt{a^2+x^2}-a\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2} \left(\sqrt{a^2+x^2}+a\right)\left(\sqrt{a^2+x^2}-a\right)}-\frac{1}{x}$$

Just finish.

Comment: And now the only "tricky" step is noticing that you can simplify $\left(\sqrt{a^2+x^2}+a\right)\left(\sqrt{a^2+x^2}-a\right)$

Answer (score 2):

Small error: a missing + sign in the fourth line from the product rule:

$$=\left(\frac{x}{a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}}\right)\left((x^{-1})'\left(a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}\right) ~~\mathbf{+}~~ x^{-1}\frac{d}{dx}\left(a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}\right)\right)$$

Continuing on with your idea, the next step would be to use the chain rule on that square root; with the + sign in the proper place we get

$$=\left(\frac{x}{a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}}\right) \left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\left(a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}\right) ~~\mathbf{+}~~ \frac{1}{x}\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}}\right)$$

Then the main trick is to get a common denominator:

$$=\left(\frac{x}{a+\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}}\right) \frac{-a\sqrt{a^2+x^2}-a^2-x^2 + x^2}{x^2\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}$$

and I'm sure you can take it from here.